# is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account?

Tags: scala, twilio

I am trying to send message to my verified phone number, which I see on

[image]

and I send it from number that I get from

[image]

My code looks like

```
object TextMessage {
  def send() = {
    // Create a rest client
    val client: TwilioRestClient = new TwilioRestClient("AC*****", "324324234******")
    val mainAccount: Account = client.getAccount
    val messageFactory: SmsFactory = mainAccount.getSmsFactory
    var messageParams: List[NameValuePair] = List[NameValuePair]()

    messageParams = messageParams :+ new BasicNameValuePair("To", "MyVerifiedNumber")
    messageParams = messageParams :+ new BasicNameValuePair("From", "NumberIGotFromTwilio")
    messageParams = messageParams :+ new BasicNameValuePair("Body", "The system crashed just now!")

    println(messageParams)
    messageFactory.create(ListBuffer(messageParams).flatten)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    TextMessage.send()
  }
}
```

When I run, I get the following

```
Exception in thread "main" com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException: The From phone number +1NumberIGotFromTwilio is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException.parseResponse(TwilioRestException.java:74)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioClient.safeRequest(TwilioClient.java:509)
    at com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.SmsList.create(SmsList.java:79)
    at com.shn.enterpriseconnector.util.TextMessage$.send(TextMessage.scala:25)
    at com.shn.enterpriseconnector.util.TextMessage$.main(TextMessage.scala:29)
    at com.shn.enterpriseconnector.util.TextMessage.main(TextMessage.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, "NumberIGotFromTwilio" is just what you're showing in this question to hide your phone number, not the actual string you're using, right?

Comment: Megan from Twilio Developer Community team here. Can you share your import statements at the top of the file?